# Vuejs directive expression value always undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have built a pretty small jsfiddle demonstrating access directive value within bind function. Unfortunately, it always return undefined.

https://jsfiddle.net/matiascx/vz07t9wy/1/

```
bind: function(){
   console.log(this.value);
    this.el.innerText = this.value;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong hook in your directive. As the [docs say](http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions), the bind directive is called only once and doesn't get the value passed to the directive. You have to use the update directive.

```
update: function (value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.el.innerText = value;
}
```

Here is [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/vz07t9wy/2/) as an example

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but have a hint for all who might stumble upon `binding.value` being undefined for some expressions in directives.

`v-directive="someTrueValue || someObject.notExistentKey"`

You'll expect it to be:

`true || undefined === true`

But it's not true for directives. The result will be:

`undefined`

What works though is this:

`v-directive="someTrueValue || !!someObject.notExistentKey"`